# Excel VBA: Copy values AND formats efficiently

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy huge amount of data via VBA macro from one tab to another. I need to paste values and formats.

Copying only the values efficiently is done via `Range("C1").Value = Range("A1").Value`. However, I am desperately searching for a comparable solution to copy the respective cell formats without using something like this:

```
Range("A1").Copy
Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

I need to avoid using the Copy&Paste clipboard due to the fact that I do get en error message regarding not enough RAM space after several thousand copying iterations. Also, speed is of the essence.

Comment: copy the tab and adjust as needed?

Comment: In my case, this is unfortunately not a suitable solution?

Comment: the only other way I can think of is modifying the file externally using .NET and the OpenXML SDK, and that requires the file to be closed. Otherwise, you can try disabling calculations and screen updating https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/, but that is not going to solve the Excel memory leak issues

Comment: What does your format include? Is it based on certain rules?

Comment: Have you tried this "range("A1:B100").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Output").Cells(1, 1)"

Comment: @AntiDrondert I'm only interested in background colors.

Comment: @ImranMalek This is pasting the formulas including formats. However, I am interested in values only.

Comment: @Andi Did it solve "Not enough RAM" issue , if yes then you can simply add your line of code to paste the values afterwards.

Comment: @ImranMalek I didn't check with your solution as I favored @OsmanWong solution. However, I am still facing this RAM issue eventhough I am not using any `copy`anymore. I now think I am facing these issue due to the fact that the Excel sheet itself becomes very large (>150MB) and I can't save it. In the end I had to reduce the number of iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saw your reply that you are only interested in background color,

maybe try something like

```
Range("C1").Interior.Color = Range("A1").Interior.Color
```